# Bootloader Strategy for Corrupt Applications

Tags: gcc, embedded, bootloader, cortex-m

I've implemented a bootloader for a Kinetis ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller.

The main application (starting at `0x10000`) is re-programmed via the bootloader over a custom RS232 interface. I've implemented `jumpToApplication` and `jumpToBootloader` functions from the bootloader and application perspectives and all works fine so far.

One strategy I'm keen to understand is what to do upon the event of a corrupt main application?

The bootloader currently checks the stack-pointer and program-counter of the main application before deciding whether to jump. However, if the main application is corrupt then either two issues will occur:

1. The main application will hang and make it difficult to re-program
2. The microcontroller will reboot and will be stuck in a `bootloader` > `application` > `bootloader` (etc) loop

I have a `SharedData` structure which allows me to share data (via a fixed RAM location) between both the bootloader and application. I have considered adding a `rebootCounter` to this structure which would be incremented upon the `HardFaultInterrupt` being triggered in the main application.

This value could be tested in the bootloader and, depending on the counter value, a decision could be made as to whether to stay in the bootloader or try to launch the application.

Are there more "industry standard" ways of dealing with this?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, the ultimate reason for asking this question is to cover the following scenario:

1. Bootloader is programmed into the device during production phase via JTAG
2. Main application (latest build) is loaded during testing phase
3. During the testing phase, there is a power-cut or connection issue and the device is only partially programmed
4. When power is applied again, the bootloader will "assume" that there is a valid program in the main part of flash and will "jump" to this application
5. The microcontroller is now stuck in no mans land with no way of re-loading flash via the bootloader again without opening up the products enclosure and re-flashing the chip via JTAG - not something we can do when the product is in the field.

During the bootloader programming phase, the firmware is programmed and validated byte-by-byte to ensure that there is no corruption during the data transfer. If corruption occurs during this phase (bad packet due to USB hub issue, for example) then the bootloader will continue to accept re-programming commands.

**UPDATE #2**

The following post seems to be thinking along similar lines:

https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/how-to-write-a-bootloader-from-scratch

Comment: The bootloader's only task should be to _program_ the main application _flash_. Why would it need to communicate? It sounds as if you plan to execute both simultaneously... why would you check the "main application SP and PC"? If the bootloader finds that the main application flash is corrupt, then try to program it again. That's about it.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I would run both simultaneously. When the chip starts, it enters the bootloader. The bootloader accepts commands to re-program the application part for flash. You say "if the bootloader finds the main application flash is corrupt, then try to program it again" - how do I determine if the main application flash is corrupt without actually running the main application? The whole point of the two pieces of code communicating is so that I can get back to bootloader from the application in order to re-flash. How else would I achieve this if they can't communicate?

Comment: The whole reason for checking the SP and PC is just a bit of crude validation, in case there was an issue reprogramming the start of the application before jumping to the application from the bootloader.

Comment: "how do I determine if the main application flash is corrupt without actually running the main application" Ideally by comparing the flash byte by byte. Or if this isn't possible, a CRC32. I don't see how you can " get back to bootloader from the application", where does the bootloader store the application in the meantime? In another section of flash? Why would that flash be any better? And what are you actually trying to protect against - data retention?

Comment: `how do I determine if the main application flash is corrupt without actually running the main application?` - Please define "corrupt". For me "corrupt" means that a change in data occurred while transmitting and flashing the application. It looks for me, that for you "corrupt" means a situation when your code is "bad" - I believe for that the industry standard is code review. `main application will hang` how to detect "hang"iness of an application? `microcontroller will reboot`do you have any RTC or time measuring device available?

Comment: The flash programming sequence already performs a byte-byte validation when writing the application into flash (starting at address 0x10000) but what I am trying to cover is if the power is killed during programming and then when the board is powered back on - how do I stop the application from being executed because to all intents and purposes, it is corrupt. Somehow, I need to stay in the bootloader to allow further re-programming. I am not covering against bad code - this isn't my question.

Comment: Then - transfer a checksum computed over the application bytes. Have your bootloader compute the checksum from programmed data. Compare them. But anyway, you should have one byte in flash where you store bootloader "state" itself - ie. programming or like normal. So that once it enters "programming" state, it will not enter application after power down, just like you described.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I think this is the solution. I think storing the checksum at the very top of flash may also be worthwhile so that I can validate this through reboots and power cycles. If this checksum is erased at the start of the firmware update then stored at the end (once the BL has compared and verified the checksum) then only verified applications can ever be executed from the bootloader. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend that add some delay in your bootloader that waits for a firmware update process start indicator. I developed something similar; desktop application sends start byte periodically and when you connect your device, it enters bootloader mode and waits for five seconds more to get new firmware information; so it is not important whether there is valid main application on the flash or not.
Another solution to check the existing of the main application use a specific sector of the flash for firmware information, before a firmware update process erase that sector. After a successful firmware update write a specific data to that sector. In the bootloader read this sector and verify that there is a valid application on the flash.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some 'magic' value (say 0xDEAD00D) an the end of the application and only jump to the application of the magic value is there. You can have a pointer to that location at `0x10000`.

To make things more robust, program the magic value after the verify is completed.

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually doing something very similar. I've reserved the last 0x1000 bytes of flash (1 sector) for the CRC of the main application, version information, a "signature value" (such as above) as well as some other bits and pieces. Only the bootloader can write to this area and only does so once the main application has been programmed AND verified. At the start of a re-programming operation, this end sector is erased first as a fail-safe. Seems to be pretty robust and accomplishes what I need.